# Weather Conditions in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, weather

I have yet to find a city or location or date, that gives me an answer other than `Missing[NotApplicable]` to the following query.

```
WeatherData["Chicago", "Conditions", {2010, 8}]
```

That syntax works for "Temperature" and "Pressure" and "WindDirection" But not "Conditions".  In particular, if you want data returned for "Conditions" you need to add the "Value" keyword (as the responder below noted.)  Why is that?  i.e. this command works:

```
WeatherData["Chicago", "Conditions", {2010, 8}, "Value"]
```

But now, no DateTime stamps are included, so we are only left to guess when the Conditions were recorded.  (On Temperature for instance, readings are not once / hour, although typically they are once per hour.)

This is Mathematica 7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I'm getting output:

```
In[8]:= WeatherData["Chicago","Conditions",{2010,8, 1}, "Value"]  
Out[8]= {{},{},{},{},{},{},{Fog},{Fog},{Fog},{Fog},{Fog},{Fog},{},
         {},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}}
```

Do other `WeatherData[]` syntaxes return data for you?

Comment: Edited question slightly.  Yes, I get temp/pressure/wind direction just fine.

Comment: What is so special about the "value" modifier I wonder.  Without "Value" no data returned, with "Value" data is returned....

Comment: Try running `PacletSiteUpdate/@PacletSites[]`  This will update the internal code for WeatherData[], and hopefully fix the issue you're seeing.  I get results with or without "Value".

Comment: After you follow Joshua's suggestion, make sure **Preferences** > **Internet Connectivity** > **Automatic Updates** > **Automatically check for data updates** is enabled and then restart your kernel before testing again.

Comment: This looks like a bug actually.  Can you try `WeatherData["Chicago", "Conditions", {2010, 8}, "DateValue"]`

Comment: Paclet did nothing.  This is a clean install, within 4 hours of the install I was trying these things out.  My first calls to these functions took *forever* as Mathematica was installing all the indices etc. for the city and weather data.  I have had check updates all along.

Comment: Joshua hit it, WeatherData["Chicago", "Conditions", {2010, 8}, "DateValue"] works perfectly!!!!  THANKS!  I'll file a bug report on Monday.